# Why isn't the binding in a custom WPF user control for hyperlinks working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a number of places where I'm using the following XAML code to create a hyperlink (done this way so my convention-based binding via Caliburn Micro hooks up an event with the same name as the control):

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButton}" x:Name="AddFile">
    <TextBlock>
       <Hyperlink>Add file</Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Of course, in each link I customize the name and link text. I decided to create a user control to simplify this. The XAML in the HyperlinkButton.xaml file looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleApp.UserControls.HyperlinkButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             >
    <Button Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkButton}">
        <TextBlock>
            <Hyperlink>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LinkText}"/>                
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

And in my code-behind I created a DependencyProperty for LinkText:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LinkTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LinkText", 
                                                                                         typeof(string), 
                                                                                         typeof(HyperlinkButton),
                                                                                         new UIPropertyMetadata("Fill in LinkText", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLinkTextChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(OnCoerceLinkText)));

public string LinkText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(LinkTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LinkTextProperty, value); }
}
```

Finally, I'm attempting to use the control in another file:

```
<uc:HyperlinkButton LinkText="Add File" x:Name="AddFile"/>
```

Nothing actually appears on the screen (well, except an empty spot where I expected my link).

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding in the UserControl is binding to `HyperlinkButton.DataContext.LinkText`, not `Hyperlink.LinkText`

You need to change the binding's source to point to the HyperlinkButton object instead of using the default .DataContext for the binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LinkText,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HyperlinkButton}}}"/>
```

Comment: Excellent - there is no way I would have come up with that. Thanks.